# Error Instantiating bean for org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor

Tags: java, spring

Here how my applicationContext.xml looks like:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
```

.....
.....

```
<bean id="customEditorConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
   <property name="customEditors">
        <map>
           <entry key="java.lang.String">
                <ref bean="stringTrimmerEditor"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
 </bean>
```

I am getting this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'customEditorConfigurer' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Initialization
>   of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert
>   property value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to required type
>   'java.util.Map' for property 'customEditors'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor] to
>   required type [java.lang.Class] for property
>   'customEditors[java.lang.String]': PropertyEditor
>   [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor] returned
>   inappropriate value of type
>   [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor]

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for the `setCustomEditors` method of the  CustomEditorConfigurer class](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/CustomEditorConfigurer.html#setCustomEditors(java.util.Map)) states the following (emphasis mine):

> Specify the custom editors to register via a Map, using the class name of the required type as the key **and the class name of the associated PropertyEditor as value**

So you pass in the class name, not the bean itself, as the value in each entry in the map.

Try replacing

```
<entry key="java.lang.String">
    <ref bean="stringTrimmerEditor"/>
</entry>
```

<strike>with</strike>

```
<entry key="java.lang.String"
       value="org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor" />
```

with

```xml
<entry key="java.lang.String">
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor">
        <!-- change the value as necessary.  --> 
        <constructor-arg name="emptyAsNull" value="false" />  
    </bean>
</entry>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. After doing the change you suggested, now I am getting:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor.<init>()

Comment: @Chandan: sorry my previous suggestion didn't work.  I've edited my answer to come up with another suggestion - does this work for you?

Comment: @Chandan: I've edited my answer again to come up with something that works - I've tested it.  Apologies for not having tested my previous suggestions.